# Why ismy nameValue, amountValue and dateValue undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to append a tr element to a tbody element, it works but when the tr is shown, the td is undefined, NaN and undefined. I try to get the value from the input elements and submit the tr of data to tbody.

Do you guys have any idea of where i went wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Expense tracker remake</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Expense tracker</h1>
  <div class="bold" id="name">Name of Item: </div>  <input type="text">
  <div class="bold" id="amount">Amount: </div> <input type="text">
  <div class="bold" id="date">Date: </div> <input type="date">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button> <button id="clear">Clear all</button>
  <table>
      <thead>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Date</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody">
      </tbody>
  </table>



      <script>
    
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var date = document.getElementById("date");
    var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    
    
    
    submit.addEventListener("click",function(){
      var nameValue = name.value;
      var amountValue = amount.value;
      var dateValue = date.value;
    
    
         var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.innerHTML += "<td>"+nameValue+ " </td><td>"+ + amountValue+ "</td><td>" + dateValue+ "</td>";
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
    
            console.log(name.value);
    
    })
    
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

1. Your `name`, `amount` and `date` elements are a divs, not an inputs, so when you trying to read from `name.value` you are trying to read from empty div.
2. Some words in javascript are reserved and sometimes when you using those your code could works in strange way. One of those words is `name`. [Source](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/reserved_words.php).

The working demo of your code you can find here: [jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/3d86rmcq/1/).

As you can see, I've just pointed to input instead of div (by calling `nextElementSibling` because your input is a next element of your div) and changing variables names for avoiding name conflicts. Also, I have removed unnecessary doubled plus signs from `tr.innerHtml += ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You have added an extra + in html string which you are using to append tr element.

```
tr.innerHTML += "<td>"+nameValue+ " </td><td>" + amountValue+ "</td><td>" + dateValue+ "</td>";
```

Comment: Do you mean like this?
Deleting the plus in +=

tr.innerHTML = "<td>"+nameValue+ " </td><td>" + amountValue+ "</td><td>" + dateValue+ "</td>";

When i tried it, it didn't work

Comment: the + in amountValue variable. You had two of them.

Comment: Thanks, when i deleted on of the two +, it changed the value from NaN to undefined.

But still noe way to find the value of the input textbox

Comment: Perhaps you might be using different id to access the element. A look at your html code would be helpful to identify your issue specifically.

Comment: I added the html

Comment: You are accessing the value of the div which is non existant. Maybe you should get the Input element and access that value.